# Where could I find com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceManager and com.ibm.websphere.bo.BOFactory jar files?

Tags: eclipse, rad, websphere-6.1

I am working on RAD(WebSphere Portal Server 6.1v) and i am getting java build path error for ServiceManager and BOFactory jar files.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is part of WebSphere Process Server. These jar files are located in the `<INSTALL_ROOT>/plugins` directory

- `BOFactory` is located in `com.ibm.soacore.runtime_6.1.0.jar`
- `ServiceManager` is located in `com.ibm.soacore.sca_6.1.0.jar`

You need to have the server or the client jars installed on the machine you are developing on.

Comment: i installed it, added the jars to my project but for some reason it is not detecting the jars and i keep getting compile errors...

Comment: @bouncingHippo: Hard to tell why that is happening. Are you running the same setup as the OP?